# R/XLL: Interface to call XLL method in R

Tags: python, excel, r, interface, xll

I am trying to call the methods defined in the XLL addin(for Excel) from R.

Something similar to this Python code:

```
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Path  = 'myxll.xll'
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.RegisterXLL(Path)

# function call from excel
# =xllfunction("param1","param2",...)

result = xlApp.run('xllfunction', "param1","param2",...)
```

Is there any library in R that does the XLL interface? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

rcom + statconnDCOM is what you need. rcom is on CRAN so you can do install.packages("rcom")

statconnDCOM is available here: http://rcom.univie.ac.at/